# cart is not updating properly, same product is being added multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The screenshot is the problem I am getting. There is a product named "Adidas Fit Shirt". It is being added multiple times instead of only incrementing the value. I am attaching three files that are referenced to the problem. If you need any more reference, then please ask for it. Please help me to resolve the issue.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJyYn.jpg)

I am attaching code snippets:

CartScreen.js

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Store } from "../Store";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/esm/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/esm/Col";
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CartScreen() {
    const {state, dispatch: ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store);
    const { 
        cart: {cartItems},
    } = state;

    const updateCartHandler = async(item, quantity) => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
        if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
            window.alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
            return;
          }
          ctxDispatch({
            type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
            payload: {...item, quantity},
          }); 
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <Helmet>
        <title>Shopping Cart</title>
        </Helmet>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
            <MessageBox>
            Cart is Empty <Link to="/">Go Shopping</Link>
            </MessageBox>
        ) : (
            <ListGroup>
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
                <ListGroup.Item key = {item.id}>
                <Row className="align-items-center">
                <Col md={4}>
                <img src={item.image}
                alt = {item.image}
                className="img-fluid rounded img-thumbnail"
                ></img>{' '}
                <Link to={`/product/${item.slug}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                <Button onClick={() => updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity - 1)} variant="light" disabled={item.quantity === 1}>
                <i className="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                </Button>{' '}
                <span>{item.quantity}</span>{' '}
                <Button onClick={() => updateCartHandler(item, item.quantity + 1)} variant="light" disabled={item.quantity === item.countInStock}>
                <i className="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </Button>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>${item.price}</Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                <button variant="light">
                <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
                </Col>
                </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
            </ListGroup>
        )}
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
        <Card.Body>
        <ListGroup variant="flush">
        <ListGroup.Item>
        <h3>
        Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)}{' '}
        items) : $
        {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.quantity, 0)}
        </h3>
        </ListGroup.Item>
        <ListGroup.Item>
                  <div className="d-grid">
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="primary"
                    //   onClick={checkoutHandler}
                      disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
                    >
                      Proceed to Checkout
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
        </Card.Body>
        </Card>
        </Col>
        </Row>
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Badge';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Store } from './Store';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';


function App() {
  const {state} = useContext(Store); 
  const {cart} = state;
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="d-flex flex-column site-container">
      <header>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
      <LinkContainer to="/">
      <Navbar.Brand>Panchtatva</Navbar.Brand>
      </LinkContainer>
      <Nav className="me-auto">
                  <Link to="/cart" className="nav-link">
                    Cart
                    {cart.cartItems.length > 0 && (
                      <Badge pill bg="danger">
                        {cart.cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.quantity, 0)}
                      </Badge>
                    )}
                  </Link>
                </Nav>
      </Container>
      </Navbar>
      </header>
      <main>
      <Container className="mt-3">
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/product/:slug" element={<ProductScreen />} />
      <Route path="/cart" element={<CartScreen />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
      </Routes>
      </Container>
      
      </main>
      <footer>
      <div className="text-center">All Rights Reserved</div>
      </footer>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import { Navigate, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup'
import Rating from "../components/Rating";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card'
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge'
import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet-async';
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import {getError} from "../utils";
import { Store } from "../Store";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, product: action.payload, loading: false };
    case "FETCH_FAIL":
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function ProductScreen() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const { slug } = params;

  const [{ loading, error, product }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    product: [],
    loading: true,
    error: "",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH REQUEST" });
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(`/api/products/slug/${slug}`);
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: result.data });
      } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_FAIL", payload: getError(err) });
      }
      // setProducts(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [slug]);

  const {state, dispatch: ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store);
  const {cart} = state;
  const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    const existItem = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x._id === product._id);
    const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`);
    if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
      window.alert('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
      return;
    }
    ctxDispatch({ 
      type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM',
      payload: {...product, quantity},
    });
    navigate('/cart');
  };

  return loading ? (
    <LoadingBox />
  ): error ? (
    <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
  ): (
    <div>
    <Row>
    <Col md={6}>
    <img className="img-large" src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
    </Col>
    <Col md={3}>
    <ListGroup variant="flush">
    <ListGroup.Item>
    <Helmet>
    <title>{product.name}</title>
    </Helmet>
    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    </ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item>
    <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews}></Rating>
    </ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}
    </ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item>
    Description: 
    <p>{product.description}</p>
    </ListGroup.Item>
    </ListGroup>
    </Col>
    <Col md={3}>
    <Card>
    <Card.Body>
    <ListGroup variant="flush">
    <ListGroup.Item>
    <Row>
    <Col>Price: </Col>
    <Col>${product.price} </Col>
    </Row>
    </ListGroup.Item>
    <ListGroup.Item>
    <Row>
    <Col>Status: </Col>
    <Col>{product.countInStock > 0 ? (
      <Badge bg="success">In Stock</Badge>
    ): (
      <Badge bg="danger">Unavailable</Badge>
    )}
    </Col>
    </Row>
    </ListGroup.Item>
    {product.countInStock > 0 && (
      <ListGroup.Item>
        <div className="d-grid">
          <Button onClick={addToCartHandler} variant="primary">
            Add to Cart
          </Button>
        </div>
      </ListGroup.Item>
    )}
    </ListGroup>
    </Card.Body>
    </Card>
    </Col>
    </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: Did you write this code? You included a lot of code, but didn't include the `Store` context that handles `CART_ADD_ITEM` - which is more likely to be where the problem is.

Comment: Error has been resolved. There was an error in Store context. Thankyou